# Can I use SQL syntax on SimpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml, where-clause

Can I use a `WHERE` selector (like SQL syntax) on SimpleXML?

**Example XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<documentElement>
        <row>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>David</name>
            <surname>Johnson</surname>
        </row>
        <row>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Jack</name>
            <surname>Nixon</surname>
        </row>
</documentElement>
```

**My Example Where Selector**

```
$where = "Jack";
$xml = "example.xml";
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($sxml->row as $data=>$row)
{
if ($where == $data->name) // some code here
else // other some code here
}
```

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: The only reason your sample code doesn't work as it is, is that you've muddled the key of the loop (`$data`) with the value (`$row`). You want `$row->name` not `$data->name`. Still, XPath is probably closest to what you were thinking of when SQL came into your head.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way: [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

```
$where = "Jack";
$xml = "example.xml";
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($sxml->xpath('/documentElement/row/name[.="'.$where.'"]/..'));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do this:

```
$where = "Jack";
$xml = "example.xml";
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($sxml->row as $row)
{
    if ($row->name == $where) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // other some code here
    }
}
```